# React native bluetooth enabler

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, beacon

I'm working with react-native-beacons-manager package and so far is a good package and very easy to use.
The problem is that I need bluetooth to be enabled on the phone to scan my beacons, but I haven't found any npm package or something that lets me activate bluetooth using my app. I'm using React Native and testing the app in IOS first.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to programmatically turn on Bluetooth in iOS.  The best you can do is detect it is off and prompt the user to turn it on.. (On Android, however, you can turn it on.)